# C# code to read remote task scheduler log files

Tags: c#

Can someone provide with how to read the output of a task scheduler on a remote machine using C#.

Comment: Please give some detail. What sort of task scheduler? What is the output from it (files, console output, something else)? You'll need to provide a lot more detail before anyone can answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Take a look at this:

- [WMI Tasks: Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394599%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [A Simple Guide to WMI Provider](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/wmi/article.php/c6035)